# Is it possible to renderning non-retina image using retina image programmatically at runtime?

Tags: ios, image, retina-display

is it possible to render non-retina images using retina images programmatically at runtime?

I'm developing an universal App, and there are a lot of images in my app bundle, make my app bigger and bigger and I'm trying to downsize my app....

I can't just delete all non-retina images, cause I need to support iPad mini without retina display.

So is this possible? Using retina images to render a non-retina images, will this cause fatal performance issue? or any other side effects?

Thank you very much.

**Edit1:**

@troop231 Yes, the 1st generation iPad mini and 2ed generation iPad mini both supports retina assets

@bstahlhood I thought I was doing something wrong so the universal App on 1st gen iPad mini not using the @2x images, looks like this is just another limitation from Apple.

So I guess the only solution is not to support 1st gen iPad mini or I have to add both non-retina images and retina images in my App bundle?

Comment: I thought the iPad mini on iOS 7 supports retina assets.

Comment: @troop231 He is talking about the first gen iPad Mini, which is non retina.

Comment: @bstahlhood I'm aware of that, but I'm correct: http://www.macrumors.com/2013/07/09/ios-7-leverages-retina-iphone-app-assets-to-improve-2x-mode-on-non-retina-ipads/

Comment: @troop231 Right, but that is talking about iPhone only apps displaying on an iPad that used to use the 2X mode. He is building a Universal app that would install on the iPad using native resolution. It would not use this functionality.

Comment: Thats retarded Apple wouldnt do the same for Universal apps

Comment: @troop231 Yes, the 1st gen iPad mini supports retina assets but only for iPhone App running on iPad using emulation mode.

Comment: @bstahlhood Is there any work-around for this? or can I force iOS to use my retina images?

Comment: @YCK like I said, this is a dumb move to let this be for iPhone only apps and not universal

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but you need to specifically set the frame dimensions for the image in every case by the 1/2 size.

e.g. retina image is 100x100 so if you use it make sure it has CGSize(50,50)

Comment: I did use the non-retina image size for all the UI element and set a retina image for it, but looks weird. the image displayed on 1st iPad mini looks weird.

Comment: I guess just like bstahlhood said, only iPhone Apps displaying on an iPad without retina display using iPhone emulation mode would use the @2x images.